# How to recover "ipod_control" folder?

Tags: ipod

I have got iPod Shuffle 1st gen model. I accedently deleted the "ipod_control" folder when I was copying the songs on it throug my pc usb. Now it does not play any song at all. How can I recover the deleted file again?

I tried searching for a download of the folder but its not available on net. I checked the Recycle Bin of my pc, however it's not there.

Do I need iTunes to make it work again?

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution.

I installed iTunes and reset the factory setup using settings option.